# Ruby On Rails Active Admin has_many dropdown to add new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a model with self-referential has_many relation though another model.
So I have model `Product` and each product can have another products.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_connections
  has_many :related_projects, through: :project_connections,
                              dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_connections,
                                :related_projects, allow_destroy: true

  ...
end
```

and my `ProjectConnection` model:

```
class ProjectConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :related_project, class_name: Project

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :related_project

  ...
end
```

In Active Admin I want in create/edit project view to remove or add related_project.
In `admin/project.rb`

```
form do |f|
    inputs 'Продолжение проекта' do
      f.has_many :related_projects, heading: 'Добавьте проект', allow_destroy: true, new_record: true  do |i|
        i.input :id, as: :select, collection: Project.all, include_blank: false
      end
    end
end
```

http://localhost:3000/admin/projects/1/edit
[image][image]

After I add new related_project and press Update Project, nothing was changed.
So what should I do to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved problem by myself. As ProjectConnection store connections between projects {id, project_id, related_project_id}, it would be correct to manipulate with `projects.project_connections`, not `projects.related_projects`. First, I declared a structure of params for `projects.project_connections` in `admin/project.rb`:

```
project_connections_attributes: [
  :id,
  :project_id,
  :related_project_id,
  :_destroy
]
```

Then instead of

```
inputs 'Продолжение проекта' do
  f.has_many :related_projects, heading: 'Добавьте проект', allow_destroy: true, new_record: true  do |i|
    i.input :id, as: :select, collection: Project.all, include_blank: false
  end
end
```

I wrote

```
inputs 'Продолжение проекта' do
  f.has_many :project_connections, heading: 'Добавьте проект', allow_destroy: true, new_record: true  do |i|
    i.input :related_project_id, as: :select, collection: Project.all, include_blank: false
    i.input :project_id, :input_html => { :value => f.object.id }, as: :hidden
  end
end
```

It works perfectly)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to have a abstract field on the project, connected_project_ids, and a before_save filter to persist the changes, and an after load to fill the field for initializing the form

```
before_save   :connect_projects
after_find    :set_connected_project_ids
attr_accessor :connected_project_ids

def set_connected_project_ids
  self.connected_project_ids = connected_projects.pluck(:related_project_id)
end

def connect_projects
  connected_ids = connected_projects.pluck(:related_project_id)

  #projects that are in connected_project_ids, but not yet associated
  projects_to_connect = connected_project_ids - connected_ids
  projects_to_connect.each do |cp_id|
    connected_projects.create(related_project_id: cp_id) 
  end

  #projects that are associated, but not in connected_project_ids
  projects_to_disconnect = connected_ids - connected_project_ids
  projects_to_disconnect.each do |cp_id|
    connected_projects.where(related_project_id: cp_id).destroy_all
  connected_ids
end
```

this would allow you to add and remove associated projects by submitting the array of project ids it should now be associated with in the connected_project_ids field.